# Map function output record is zero - No errors but still mapper is not giving any output. (Map Reduce)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, computer-science, bigdata

Trying processing of text to get Parts Of Speech using hadoop map reduce. No errors but still map function is not giving any output.

```
public class POSCount {
  public static class TokenizerMapper
   extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>{
//private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();
   private  Map<String, String> wordList = null;


@Override
public void setup(Context context) {
    Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    Path pt = new Path("/user/gokul/hw1b/mobyposi.i");
    //Path pt = new Path("/user/gxs161530/mobyposi.i");
    BufferedReader br;
    try {
    //FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(pt)));
    wordList = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String line, word, type;
    char ch;
      while ((line=br.readLine())!= null){
          word = line.substring(0,line.indexOf("×"));
          type = line.substring(line.indexOf("×")+1);
          for(int i=0;i<type.length();i++){
              ch = type.charAt(i);
              switch (ch){
                case 'N' :  wordList.put(word, "noun");
                            break;
                case 'p' :  wordList.put(word, "plural");
                            break;
                case 'V' :  wordList.put(word, "verb");
                            break;
                case 't' :  wordList.put(word, "verb");
                            break;
                case 'i' :  wordList.put(word, "verb");
                            break;
                case 'A' :  wordList.put(word, "adjective");
                            break;
                case 'v' :  wordList.put(word, "adverb");
                            break;
                case 'C' :  wordList.put(word, "conjunction");
                            break;
                case 'P' :  wordList.put(word, "preposition");
                            break;
                case 'r' :  wordList.put(word, "pronoun");
                            break;
                case 'D' :  wordList.put(word, "definite article");
                            break;
                case 'I' :  wordList.put(word, "indefinite article");
                            break;
                case 'o' :  wordList.put(word, "nominative");
                            break;
              }
         }
       }
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
//  return map;
}
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
  String token;
  int len=0;
  try {
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
         token = itr.nextToken().trim().toLowerCase();   
         len = token.length();
         if(wordList.containsKey(token) && len>=5){ 
            word.set(wordList.get(token));
            //context.write(new Text(Integer.toString(len)), word);
            context.write(new IntWritable(len), word);
            }
      }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }     
 }
```

Above programs returns Map output record as 0.  I need (Length,parts-of-speech) as output from map . Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in setup

Comment: can you provide the input you are running it against. To me it appears there is some mistake in your map method logic. But i cannot be sure without sample of input file you are using

Comment: List of words indicating parts of speech:
aboveground×A,
above×PvNA,
abox×A,
Abo×N,
abo×NA,

Comment: Each of these pair of words are in separate lines or are they all in a same line.Give me exact format of your input so that I can test it on my system.

Comment: They ares separated by lines without comma. Couldn't paste it here line by line.

Comment: http://icon.shef.ac.uk/Moby/mpos.html .Downloaded .i file from this link

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fine I ran it aginst some sample taken out of the file you mentioned in comment and it gave me expected outputs. But when I ran the same program against whole file then it gave me error due to some notation problem, as I figured it out. It was not able to get 'x' out of the input file in a format which java supports. So I copied all the data from that file into new file (stack.txt) and then ran program again and it gave me output.

I used same mapper as given in your question and this is the reducer I used

```
// Do not go on logic it was just for testing
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
Text t = new Text();
for(Text i : values)
{
t=i;
}   
    context.write(t, key);
}
```

this is the result I got

```
verb    5
verb    6
noun    7
noun    8
noun    9
adjective       10
noun    11
noun    12
noun    13
adjective       14
adjective       15
adjective       16
noun    17
noun    18
adjective       19
```

Let me know if you still face some issue

Comment: Getting o/p only if I use following in mapper : context.write(word, new IntWritable(len)); If context.write(new IntWritable(len), word) is used. I'm getting same problem.

Comment: Got the output. Updated the job.setMapOutputKeyClass now. Thanks a lot for the help !!